# non payable function with payable modifier

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, hardhat, openzeppelin-contracts

I have a non payable function to propose function. It has a modifier called isSubmitFeePaid. Modifier call a payable function. I am writing a script to propose. But problem is when i try call purpose its revert with FundProject__NotEnoughPayment() which i didnt sent eth. But i cant because it is not payable.
Because of it has payable modifier i have to sent some eth. I cant make purpose function payable. Its OpenZeppelin(governance) function its overriding and doesnt like to be payable. Have can i solve this?

```
 modifier isSubmitFeePaid() {
    paySubmitFee();
    _;
}
function paySubmitFee() public payable {
    if (msg.value < enteranceFee) {
        revert FundProject__NotEnoughPayment();
    }
    projectOwners = payable(msg.sender);
}


function propose(
    address[] memory targets,
    uint256[] memory values,
    bytes[] memory calldatas,
    string memory description
) public override(Governor, IGovernor) isSubmitFeePaid returns (uint256) {
    return super.propose(targets, values, calldatas, description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick would be to create another method which calls the propose method. You can make this wrapper a payable method and attach the isSubmitFeePaid modifier to it.

Comment: Technically your are right but That will not work. Because anybody can call propose function without pay.

Comment: make `propose` internal, then.

Comment: openzeppelin didnt like that either. Giving this error: overriding function visibility differs.